# Join to another table when the join column is null

Tags: oracle, join, null

I have a sql that is selecting many things from the database however I would like that data to only comeback which is matched to a personal table I have. 
I would like to join a column [vin_code] from my table [population] however there are nulls in here and were there are nulls I would like to join another column from my table to another table in the database.

I will give an example sql below:

```
Select distinct v.kegal_rntity_id
From vin v
  Inner join ops$dami.population pop
          On v.vin_code = pop.vin_code
```

Then were pop.vin_code is null I would like to join pop.vis_code on a table in the database called zegal_rentity z column z.vis_code

So something like

```
join zegal_rentity z
On pop.vis_code = z.vis_code
```

But I only want to do this were pop.vin_code is null

Comment: Please show some example input/expected output. It doesn't need to be real data, just representative of the problem. It's hard to see what you're trying to do here.

Comment: In my own table I have 1.5million records out those records 1.4million have Vin codes eg 12345678 and these can be matched to the main database to bring back the customer name example John Smith however I would also like to match the remaining 100k but these only have a vis code eg abcdef there is another table in the database which this can be matched to. So I would like to join the table first on the 1.4million vin codes to get the customer name and then remaining 100k on the vis code to get the name. I can get the first 1.4m simply on a inner join but don’t know what to do next

Answer (score 0):

As sample data is not available, I am unable to test the solution but try the following query with condition based `outer join`.

```
Select distinct v.kegal_rntity_id
From ops$dami.population pop
Left join vin v 
On v.vin_code = pop.vin_code
Left join zegal_rentity z
On (case when pop.vin_code is null and
pop.vis_code = z.vis_code then 1 end = 1);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you so much I have tried the above sql but query was running for 4 plus hours without returning results